# Boto MTurkRequestError: 200 OK

Tags: django, boto, mechanicalturk

I recently upgraded to boto 2.6, to fix an S3 broken pipe issue. Unfortunately, the new version seems to be causing problems with MTurk.

Anytime I try to post a hit on MTurk, I get the following:

```
MTurkRequestError: 200 OK
<CreateHITResponse><OperationRequest>
<RequestId>ee3cc3a5-177a-4081-a4ae-a42663a25ece</RequestId>
<Errors><Error><Code>AWS.BadClaimsSupplied</Code><Message>The specified claims are invalid.
```

My connection to MTurk works fine. I'm also able to create a question object. My code only fails when I try to create a hit:

```
# connect to mturk
  conn = MTurkConnection(aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                      aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
                      host=host) 

 # create question object
 q = ExternalQuestion(external_url=settings.URL_ROOT + hit.get_absolute_url(), frame_height=800)

 #this line fails
 create_hit_rs = conn.create_hit(question=q)
```

Does anyone know what "BadClaimsSupplied" might mean? There was some discussion about this [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/boto-users/1EcL6BIFEdo/Om-O_sxy8QEJ), but I'm having trouble implementing the solutions. I don't want to modify the boto library directly because I'm deploying to heroku.

Comment: I'd suggest asking this on the AWS developer forum: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=11. Someone from AWS will be able to look at your request and tell you what went wrong.

Comment: This is a known issue and it has been resolved in the latest boto update

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue as seen in ticket https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/1056

Recommend you upgrade to newer version!

Regards,